# GNU Octave: How to make sure vectors in random matrix are unique?

Tags: random, matrix, unique, octave, gnu

creating an MxN matrix of random integer values in GNU Octave is very easy:

```
K = randi(k, M, N)
```

where k is the maximum value.

However, I have the requirement that each column vector in this matrix should be unique. Is there a clever way to ensure this in Octave? I could, of course, loop over all columns and calculate the pair-wise difference between all possible pairing of column vectors. But that seems a bit cumbersome.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options would be to use [`unique`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sets.html) to eliminate duplicate columns, and compare the dimensions of the result with the dimensions of the original matrix. Note that we need to transpose the matrix to be able to use the `rows` parameter to unique.

```
# Non unique columns

octave> K=[1 2 1; 2 2 2]
K =
   1   2   1
   2   2   2

octave> isequal(size(unique(K','rows')), size(K'))
ans = 0

# Unique columns

octave> K=[1 2 3; 2 2 2]
K =    
   1   2   3
   2   2   2

octave> isequal(size(unique(K','rows')), size(K'))
ans =  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joachim. This works nicely. I looked at the unique() function, but seem to have missed that 'rows' parameter.